# Trying to load an php array into an echo that prints an image

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to get images to load into a page using the file names from an array,

This is what I have so far

```
<?php
$i=0;
$img=array("1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png");
while ($i<count($img))
{
echo "<img class='loadin' alt='imgg' src=" . "'http://www/images/" . $img[i] . "'" . "/" . ">" . "<br/>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

It seems to ignore the file name and just enters:

```
http://www/images/
```

as the source and ignores the file name from the array

Any Help would be great Thanks

Mikey

Comment: What's wrong exactly? And crazy concatenation can lead to crazy output.

Comment: That would be good to add wouldn't it lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the dollar sign with your `$i` variable:  `$img[$i]`

EDIT:
(btw. using a foreach-loop would be easier...)

```
foreach($img AS $filename) {
    echo "<img class='loadin' alt='imgg' src='http://www/images/" . $filename . "'/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is one of my favorite parts of PHP.